# How to reload an SSH session state?

Tags: ssh

How do you save your current SSH state on a remote machine and then recall that state at a later point?

I have seen it done but not sure of the software involved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "current SSH state", but maybe you're referring to the 'screen' program. This can be used to run programs on the remote host (typically a shell) and then be "detached" and reattached when logging in later. One can also resume a screen session after an SSH session got disconnected.

Comment: Yeah, must be `screen` Hamish is having in mind....

Comment: All hail the `screen` program!

Answer (score 1):

You need either [GNU `screen`](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) or (even better still) [`tmux`](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/)!

When working on remote hosts, I always start a `screen` session (or `tmux` if it's available). It means that if I get disconnected (deliberately or otherwise) I do not lose any work.